# After changing a key value from a machine2, Not getting the changed value from Machine1

Tags: appfabric

I did a sample application & run the application from 2 different machines where both application is using AppFabric cache. I set the pollInterval="120" secs in both applications config file with below settings:

```
<localCache isEnabled="true" 
            sync="NotificationBased" 
            ttlValue="300" 
            objectCount="10"/>

<!--(optional) specify cache notifications poll interval-->
<clientNotification pollInterval="120" />
```

Also enabled Notification in cluster using powershell.

Now from Machine1 I read the key called key1 whose value is "Value1".
then from Machine2 I changed the value of key1 to "Changed".
then from Machine2 I read the key called key1 whose value is now displayed as "Changed".
then after the poll interval period which is 2 mnts I read the key called key1 from Machine1, whose value is now displayed still as "Value1". Why it's not displaying "Changed".

Why the change is not detected by the application in Machine1?  Why the local cache invalidation not occurring?

At Ahmed Ilyas:>
show the code you are using to read and write to the cache. you also have not explained how you configured AppFabric and these machines. are they joined to the cluster?

I have done reading through AFC Read-Through API. which is done in separate project. Write to cache is done just by Put() method. As this is a sample project, so I though no need to update the  database only update at cache cluster.

The above config settings for each application running in 2 machines.
I have allowed access for these 2 machines by granting access to them in cache cluster. 1 machine is both AFC server & cache client(i.e Machine1).

Hope this helps you to answer. Find the code below:

```
public class CacheUtil
```

{

```
private static DataCacheFactory _factory = null;
    private static DataCache _cache = null;
static CacheUtil()
{
  if (_cache == null)
  {
    // Declare array for cache host(s).
    DataCacheServerEndpoint[] servers = new DataCacheServerEndpoint[1];
    servers[0] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("H1011.hoboo.net", 22233);
    // Set the local cache properties. In this example, it
    // is timeout-based with a timeout of 300 seconds(5mnts).
    DataCacheLocalCacheProperties localCacheConfig;
    TimeSpan localTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

    localCacheConfig = new DataCacheLocalCacheProperties(60, localTimeout, DataCacheLocalCacheInvalidationPolicy.TimeoutBased);
    // Setup the DataCacheFactory configuration.
    DataCacheFactoryConfiguration factoryConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
    //factoryConfig.ChannelOpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    //factoryConfig.Servers = servers;
    //factoryConfig.LocalCacheProperties = localCacheConfig;

    _factory = new DataCacheFactory();
    //_factory = new DataCacheFactory(factoryConfig);
    _cache = _factory.GetCache("default");
  }


}

public static DataCache GetCache()
{
  if (_cache != null) return _cache;

  try
  {
    RuntimeContext.WriteAppFabricErrorLog(new AppFabricLogger()
    {
      CacheKey = "Connected to AppFabric Cache Server.",
      CacheData = "Connected to AppFabric Cache Server.",
      ErrorString = "Connected to AppFabric Cache Server."
    });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Suppress Error
  }
  return _cache;
}
```

}

Other class which has Get():>

```
    public static object Get(string pName)
{
  object cachedItem = null;
  try
  {
    //Check configuration settings for AppFabric.
    bool appFabricCache;
    bool.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppFabricCache"], out appFabricCache);
    if (appFabricCache)
    {
      //Get data from AppFabric Cache Server.
      cachedItem = CacheUtil.GetCache().Get(pName);
    }
    else
    {
      //Get data from Local Cache Server.
      cachedItem = RuntimeContextOlderVersion.Get(pName);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception Ex)
  {
    //If failes, write reason to log file.
    WriteAppFabricErrorLog(new AppFabricLogger()
    {
      CacheKey = pName,
      CacheData = "Get Method",
      ErrorString = Ex.ToString()
    });
  }
  return cachedItem;
}
```

> @stuartd

Yes I have enabled notifictions. You can see that in my appconfig.

For Staurt:>

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-cacheconfig

cmdlet Get-CacheConfig at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
CacheName: default

CacheName                : default
TimeToLive               : 10 mins
CacheType                : Partitioned
Secondaries              : 0
MinSecondaries           : 0
IsExpirable              : True
EvictionType             : LRU
NotificationsEnabled     : True
WriteBehindEnabled       : False
WriteBehindInterval      : 300
WriteBehindRetryInterval : 60
WriteBehindRetryCount    : -1
ReadThroughEnabled       : True
ProviderType             : SampleProvider.Provider,SampleProvider, Version=1.0.
                           0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cde85af3c5f6411
                           e
ProviderSettings         : {"DBConnection"="Database=Test123;Server=***.***.**.
                           **;uid=****;pwd=*****;connection timeout=5000"}

Comment: show the code you are using to read and write to the cache. you also have not explained how you configured AppFabric and these machines. are they joined to the cluster?

Comment: You have to enable notifications in the cache you are using, not in the cluster.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas  Updated the details.  You can see that in my original question

Comment: @stuartd  updated the details Stuartd.Yes I have enabled notifictions.   You can see that in my appconfig.

Comment: @AsifAbdulla I meant on the cache cluster, not in the local cache, so the command `Get-CacheConfig CacheName` returns `NotificationsEnabled : True`

Comment: @stuartd Yes I have enabled on cache cluster also. You can see that in my get-cacheconfig result that I have added above.